# Spark - Read file in byte format as InputStream

Tags: java, apache-spark, inputstream, rdd

how can i read multiple  files , in byte array format , as input stream in a spark job?

```
Path pt = new Path(umfPaths);           
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(jsc.hadoopConfiguration());
fs.open(pt);
```

.. The reason is I have inputfiles whose contents is in byte format . The input file is then split into multiple files with blocklength size as 64 MB and stored in HDFS. I have to parallel process the files using Apache spark . The req is to read one entire block of 64MB as a single file and process it . Is it efficient to process by writing a custom record reader or use the FileSystem API's (using InputStream) to read each file ?

Comment: What's the purpose of doing that if I may ask? PS: you seem to have pending answers to be accepted on old question you have asked, would you please do that and up vote them since they seem to be solved.

Comment: Hi , I cannot upvote but I tagged them  as solved.

Comment: No problem. Can you answer please the question I asked you? (What's the purpose of doing what you are trying?)

Comment: I have just edited my question with some more details . Pls let me know  if u need more details

Comment: But spark will take care of the partitioning, why are you torturing yourself? (You can of course set a partition size on spark also) You'll just need to specify the inputformat while reading with sc.newhadoopapifile(...)

Comment: Ok . The point I am confused is that my input is not sequence or text , but Byte . WIll this work with newhadoopapifile ? I will do a search on this and will try this .

Comment: *All* files are 'in byte format'. This information adds nothing.

Comment: The content of the file , ie the data itself is in byte format . The data is fed from MainFrames .

Comment: To be more precise . The records that my files contain are converted into byte array format and each file will contain a specific number of records so that one record wont get splitted into multiple Blocks , when stored in HDFS .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue with using the API in SparkContext  , newHadoopApiFile .
I have written a CustomInputFormat class which will do InputFormat thing and will return a POJO Object .

> JavaPairRDD> baseRDD =
>   sc.newAPIHadoopFile(args[2], InputFormat.class, NullWritable.class,
>   ArrayList.class, conf);

Then ignore the Key and just create an RDD of  Values .

> JavaRDD> mapLines1 = baseRDD.values();

Then Did a FlatMap of the above RDD .

Inside the InputFormat class I extended the FileInputFormat and the override the isSplittable to false to read as a single file .

> ```
> public class InputFormat extends  FileInputFormat {    
>  public
>  RecordReader<NullWritable, ArrayList<Record>> 
>   createRecordReader(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context)
>  throws IOException, InterruptedException{  //Logic Goes here  }
>
>       @Override
>           protected boolean isSplitable(JobContext context, Path file) {             return false;     
> } 
> }
> ```